# How to determine whether a series converges when it contains ɛ >0?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=2}^{∞} \frac{1}{n\times ln(n)^{1+\epsilon}}$$

With $\epsilon > 0$

I'm unsure how to prove convergence. I'm allowed to use $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ ln $(n)^{\epsilon} = \infty$  without proof.

So how would I prove convergence?

Comment: Would you mind integrating a similar-looking function?

Answer (score 0):

It is more appreciative if you post your try. This is my comment:

It is easy to check that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln^{-1-\varepsilon} {(n)}}{n}$ converges whenever $\varepsilon >0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Integral Test, which then you can apply $$\lim_{n \to \infty}
(n)^{\epsilon} = \infty
$$ to show that the integral converges.